# Drop-down Selected Value not Showing in my Detailview

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have drop-down that is not showing the previoiusly selected value in my Detailview.  It always shows me the first value in the list.  If the previously selected value was xyz then when the Detailvies loads, i want to show xyz.  I have researched a lot but could not find any solution that i can use.  please help
here is my aspx code for the field that has the dropdown

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name:">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_UID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Name") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate> 
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Name" Width="200px" Height="25" DataSourceID="SDS_Manager" DataTextField="FULL_NM" AutoPostBack="false"
         DataValueField="UID" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="false">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select Name" Value="Select Name"></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>                    
      </EditItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

here is the code behind that binds the detailview

```
protected void Edit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).Parent.Parent)
        { 
            sqlcon.Open();
            sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select PRJ_ID, WPC_CD, WPC_DESC, Name FROM myTable  where PRJ_ID = '" + myvar + "' ", sqlcon);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            sqlcon.Close();
            DV_Edit.DataSource = dt;
            DV_Edit.DataBind();
            sqlcon.Close();

            popup.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have even tried this but does not work SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Name") %>'>

Answer (score 0):

Try setting AutoPostBack="true" and make sure if you have any logic to set the value of the drop down in the page load, that the code is not executed on post back as shown below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        ddlOne.DataSource = //your data here;
        ddlOne.DataBind();
    }
}
//if you don't wrap this logic in the if(!IsPostBack), the code will simply re-populate
//the drop down and set the selected index to the first item in the list with each
//post back.
```